# Select dentro de um button não funciona no Firefox

Tags: firefox, html-select

Tenho um select dentro de button da seguinte forma:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                id="l_ns"
                data-toggle="button">
                Choose the N to be stage
        <select  id='n_selector'
                 class="btn btn-primary"
                 data-toggle="dropdown"
                 rel="tooltip"
                 data-placement="right"
                 aria-labelledby="dropdownMenun"
                 title="Choose the N to be staged"
                 data-bind="options: available_ns,
                    optionsCaption: 'Select...',
                    value: current_n,
                    event: { change: tnmChanged }">
        </select>
        </button>
```

No Chromium funciona normalmente, porém no Firefox ele não carrega os valores do select.
Quando retiro o select de dentro do button ele carrega os valores, porém com alinhamento centralizado. Alguma  dica?

Obrigada

Comment: Em termos de semântica não faz sentido ter um `select` dentro de um `button`... acho que devias corrigir isso.

Comment: É igual `div` dentro de `p`. Um dia não funcionava minha classe CSS herdada do `p` dentro da `div` e quando fui ver era isso. Nem tinha me ligado que tinha uma `div` dentro de um `p`.